# React router <NavLink> component activeStyle/activeClassName not working with browser history

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, redux-router

I have a router set up like this:

```
<Provider>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <BFMRoot>
            <ConnectedSwitch>
                <Route path='/' exact component={BodyWelcome} />
                <Route path='/login' component={Bodies.BodyLogin} />
                <Route path='/register' component={Bodies.BodyRegister}>
            </ConnectedSwitch>
        </BFMRoot>
    </Router>
</Provider>
```

My  components look like:

```
<NavLink to={this.prepareRouteUrl(this.props.itemName)} activeStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }} activeClassName='active'>
    <IconLabelButton
        onPress={this.props.onSelect}
        labelText={this.props.itemName}
        fontName="FontAwesome"
        iconLeftName={this.props.itemIcon}
        hab='inline'
        fluid />
</NavLink>
```

This works properly when the buttons are clicked. The navigation works properly, with the right components loading according to the path. However, when I click on the browser back/forward button, the views and path change correctly, but the active class and styles remain then same.

How can I make the active styles and class names work with the browser history (back/forward buttons)?

**The react-router version is 4.2.0**

Comment: which react-router version r u using?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN **4.2.0**

Comment: make sure your connectedswitch updates properly https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md